# Renamed apache virtual host name but returns to the old address on mac Catalina

Tags: apache, rename, virtualhost

I have changed a virtual host name to a new one, e.g)new.dev.com but it gets reverted to old.dev.com.

[image: httpd-vhosts.conf]

[image: /etc/hosts]

I've restarted pc and apache server, flushdns and deleted web cache but no luck. Keeps getting back to original address.

[image]

If you could give a tip to fix this, I'd really appreciate it. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an error and was pretty silly.
I had to update the config.php /Sites/moodle/config.php

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://mymoodle.dev.com';

After changing it to the new address, it's working okay now.